# Input to attention in TensorFlow 2.0 tutorial on "Neural machine translation with attention"

Tags: tensorflow2.0, seq2seq, attention-model

There is one question when I learned the example ["Neural machine translation with attention"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention).

```py
class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, dec_units, batch_sz):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.batch_sz = batch_sz
    self.dec_units = dec_units
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.dec_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
    self.fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

    # used for attention
    self.attention = BahdanauAttention(self.dec_units)

  def call(self, x, hidden, enc_output):
    # enc_output shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
    context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(hidden, enc_output)

    # x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
    x = self.embedding(x)

    # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
    x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)

    # passing the concatenated vector to the GRU
    output, state = self.gru(x)

    # output shape == (batch_size * 1, hidden_size)
    output = tf.reshape(output, (-1, output.shape[2]))

    # output shape == (batch_size, vocab)
    x = self.fc(output)

    return x, state, attention_weights
```

Why the attention weight is calculated by `encoder_output` and `encoder_hidden` and context vector is contacted with decoder_embedding. In my opinion, the attention weight should be calculated by `encoder_output` and every single hidden of decoder_output, and context vector should be contacted with decoder_output.

Maybe I have not understood the seq2seq with attention completely?

Answer (score 0):

The attention is called in every step of the decoder. The inputs to the decoder step are:

- previously decoded token `x` (or ground-truth token while training)
- previous hidden state of the **decoder** `hidden`
- hidden states of the encoder `enc_output`

As you correctly say, the attention the single decoder hidden states and all encoder hidden states as input which gives you the context vector.

```py
context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(hidden, enc_output)
```

The context vector gets concatenated with the embedding only after calling the attention mechanism when it is used as the input of the GRU cell.

```py
x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)
output, state = self.gru(x)
```

The variable `output` will become `hidden` in the next step of the decoder.